# Is $k = \frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}$ invertible?

Tags: calculus

I am told to compute $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\sin\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}$ where  $k$ is set to $\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}$ so that we can compute $\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{-2xk+ 1}{2x^2k}\sin k$. Now, we no longer have the $h$ in the denominator. I am told that the transformation from the function $k$ to $h = \frac{-2x^2k}{2xk +1}$ is supposed to be bijective. I would like to know how one can prove that this transformation is bijective (injective and surjective).

Also $x$ is being treated as a constant.

Comment: What is the constant in your phrase ? What is defined as the argument of the $k$ function ? Over what set is it defined ?

Comment: I am told to compute $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\sin\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}$ where  $k$ is set to $\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}$. And the transformation from $k$ to $h = \frac{-2x^2k}{2xk +1}$ is supposed to be bijective.

Comment: So, $x$ is treated as a constant. But what do all these have to do with a single limit ? Can you properly edit your question form and write the exact exercise with every details, including the point of your answer, so we can have a better understanding to help you ?

Comment: We want to get to $\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{-2xk+ 1}{2x^2k}\sin k$ so that we no longer have the $h$ in the denominator.

Comment: $k'(h)=\frac{2}{2(x+h)^2}$, which is positive where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x$ is a nonzero constant.  If we define $k$ as a function of $h$ by
$$
k = \frac{-h}{2x(x+h)},
$$
then the inverse (we get by solving a linear equation) shows $h$ as a function of $k$:
$$
h = \frac{-2kx^2}{2kx+1}
$$

**linear equation explanation**
$$
k = \frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}\tag{1}
$$

$$
2x(x+h)k = -h
\\
2x^2k+2xhk = -h
\\
2xhk+h=-2x^2k
$$

$$
(2xk+1)h=-2x^2k\tag{2}
$$
a linear equation in $h$.

Comment: How exactly is k supposed be a linear equation? I would like to show that, if possible, k is both surjective and injective.

Comment: Just moving things around doesn't change the fact that the function is not a linear equation.

Comment: You may solve that equation for $h$ by solving a linear equation.  That is what I meant.

Comment: Which linear equation are you referring to?

Comment: You may solve (1) for $h$ by solving the linear equation (2).

Comment: There was some information missing from the posted question. We're actually treating $x$ as a constant. But even then, I think that you might be misinterpreting "linear equation" to mean one that is written in one line. As a reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearEquation.html. Using this information let's set $(2xk + 1)h = -2x^2k$ to $(Ak + 1)h = Bk$, since we're treating $2x$ and $-2x^2$ as constants. Are we able to get a term involving the variable $k$ that is first-order?

Comment: When expanding $(Ak + 1)h = Bk$, we get $Akh + h = Bk$ or also $Akh + h - Bk = 0$ and so we get the term $Akh$ which involves $k$ but we also get the variable $h$ stuck on there.